# How do I find out the display manager info on Fedora 32 Mate?

Tags: fedora, mate-desktop, lightdm, display-manager

It's my first time to use Linux, Fedora and Mate environment.
I want to change the default login screen (mainly the background), but I couldn't find the way to do it.

I have done some research, and it seems to be related to the Display Manager. I am not fully sure if mine is LightDM or GDM. Is there any command that will show me the display manager info?

Comment: So my question is: is there some command line in the terminal that would show me the Display Manager information? thanks.

Comment: Better if you just edit your question to include your comment rather than hiding it down here!!!

Answer (score 1):

Found the command that would do the trick:

```
ls -al /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
```

Answer (score 0):

GDM is the default, unless you deliberately changed it; [sheldonfish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/413413/sheldonfish) found a comparison [What is LightDM and GDM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131496/what-is-lightdm-and-gdm) and it sure looks like LightDM now.

Comment: by the look of the login screen, it seems to be LightDM.. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131496/what-is-lightdm-and-gdm